# Team City multiple projects build

Tags: teamcity

my situation is the following, 
i have 2 big projects running separately on two machines  (1 for each project) sitting of course on different locations and running different build.xml files.

i want to be able to run them both in 1 click and have the product in 1 library at the end. 
meaning i can build my entire product in 1 click.

what us the best way to do so?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I would set up a build dependency between the two projects. This can be set up so that both projects always build back to back automatically.

When the first project is finished building, the artifacts you are interested in can be pulled over to the second project with the build dependency. Then, in that second project, you can configure the artifacts to be a collection of both projects' results.

You can read more about build dependencies here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Dependent+Build

If anything I said was too confusing, just let me know and I will come back to clarify.

Good luck!